# Is there any plugin available for google plus login in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, plugins

I would like to know is there any plugin available in symfony 1.4 to login with Google+.

Comment: Whaaaat????? 1.4? :D that ooold... you should use Symfony 2.5

Comment: Thanks @Stony but it is existing product for my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Wow that is some old legacy going on there.

Unfortuantly I don't know of any bundles that are still maintained for Symfony 1.

But!!!! I have heard of a legacy handler that will allow you to place you symfony 1 app into symfony 2.

https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle

This will allow you to refactor over time but that will mean you can use a symfony 2 bundle for google plus something like

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Comment: Thanks @Mattew A Thomas but how i will use it in symfony1.4?

Comment: You would need to install Symfony 2.5, then install the Wrapper Bundle, then place your Symfony 1 code into the app, then download HWIOAuthBundle. The wrapper is like using a jQuery deprecated layer js that allows deprecated code to still be executed